# Error al crear una aplicación con Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, exe

Estoy desarrollando una app sencilla que me ayudaría con mi trabajo, ya que automatiza bastante algunas cosas que tenemos que hacer frecuentemente. Estoy usando Python, Pycharm, Kivy y Pandas. En PyCharm me funciona perfectamente, y también cuando hago directamente doble click sobre el archivo o cuando la abro desde la consola. No obstante, estoy teniendo problemas para hacer un ejecutable para poder pasar a mis compañeros, ya que, al crearlo o bien la aplicación se cierra al momento o se abre pero se queda la pantalla completamente en negro. He probado varias soluciones que he visto por ahí, como desintalar e instalar Kivy de nuevo, actualizar varias dependencias, he creado el ejectuable con PyInstaller, Auto py to exe y con la guía oficial de Kivy. Ninguna de estas me funciona y ya no sé qué hacer. Es literalmente mi primer post, así que no tengo ni idea de qué archivos debo compartir para que alguien me pueda ayudar. Así que postearé mi código y un par de capturas. Cualquier cosa que deba agregar para dar más info, agradecería que me lo digáis.

```
# Importamos los paquetes  necesarios de Kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import datos_csv


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint = (0.8, 0.8)
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        self.fw_version = TextInput

    def selected(self, filename):
        datos_csv.nuevo_csv(filename[0], self.fw_version)
        quit()


class PVH(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PVH().run()
```

Por confidencialidad solo puedo enseñar el main y el .kv

```
<MyGrid>:
    id: mygrid
    cols: 1
    text: ""
    Image:
        source: "Image.png"
    Label:
        text: "Introduce la versión de fw sin números:"
    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
    FileChooserIconView:
        id:filechooser
        on_selection: mygrid.selected(filechooser.selection)
```

Output esperado: un .exe de mi aplicación que al ejecutarse abra una ventana con un elemento FileChooserIconView en el que pueda elegir un archivo. Después el programa lee y edita los datos para crear un csv en el que podré leer la información que necesito. (Esto sí que funciona en mi editor, PyCharm)

Algunos de los errores que me han salido son:

> Unable to load image

> Unable to load any valuable windows provider

> Unable to get a window, abort

> Unable to find any valuable spelling provider

Han ido variando según las soluciones que probaba, pero siempre sale alguno y la aplicación no llega a funcionar. También he probado a compartirle el .exe a un amigo para ver si él podía ejectuarlo, pero le pasa lo mismo que a mí. Estoy bastante seguro de que el problema tiene que ver con el entorno virtual, dependecias, archivos o algo así. Por lo tanto creo que no es necesario compartir más del código como tal. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.